# NSURLConnection to upload file asynchonrously?

Tags: objective-c

I'm kinda of new at ios development,
I've been reading and searching but cannot find a working example or an example of
how to upload a file from iphone to webserver asychronously..

I'm able to upload synchronously using

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

it works, but it blocks my main thread.

NSUrlConnection has this delegate `(connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:)`

but I've no idea how to implement it.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I suggest you to create new Thread where you will execute `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];`.

Comment: I have considered creating a thread for each upload, but then how would I get feedback as to the success or failure of the upload?

Answer (score 13):

I have managed to get uploading to work with NSURLConnection asynchronously with this:

```
-(NSURLRequest *)postRequestWithURL: (NSString *)url

                                data: (NSData *)data   
                            fileName: (NSString*)fileName
{

// from http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUpload

    //NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    //[urlRequest setURL:url];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *myboundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",myboundary];
    [urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    //[urlRequest addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundry] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData data]; //[NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[data length] + 512];
    [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", myboundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
    [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", myboundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    return urlRequest;
}
```

usage is as follows:

```
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [self postRequestWithURL:urlString
                                                   data:aVideo.msgvid
                                               fileName:filename];

    uploadConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: This looks similar to the code I'm picking up, and indeed the multipart boundary matches. Folks, `rand()`.

Answer (score 5):

Threading is not necessary for this kind of problem.  I would suggest you use the asynchronous functionality built into NSURLConnection:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //Get your response, do stuff
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //Show error, retry, etc
}
```

EDIT:  If you are really looking to upload a **file** and want to display a progress bar, then you should look at ASIHTTPRequest framework, which you can find more info on here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

For uploading a POST request with data using ASIHTTPRequest, you would do:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL_HERE"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"123" forKey:@"user_id"];
[request setData:someData withFileName:@"someData.jpg" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"image"];
[request setProgressDelegate:self];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Again, refer to the link above for the framework and documentation.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: Nick, could you please elaborate more on NSURLConnection to say: sending an NSData or jpeg file via this way? I'm able to download  asynchronously using this method, but it beyond me how I would set the wrappers up for a file upload. If all else fails, I will take a look at ASIHTTPResquest

Comment: I would include sample code for NSURLConnection with NSData, but I have not done that since I have always needed multipart-formdata, which is a nightmare with NSURLConnection.

Comment: one more stupid question if I may Nick. I am following the ASIHttprequest method, now in the delegate [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)]; how would I change this to be able to pass in an extra variable? say an nsstring?

Answer (score 2):

You cant create new thread for that task:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(upload:) toTarget:self withObject:data];
```

And when you will finish uploading, just call some implemented method in your main thread (for example `uploaded`):

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uploaded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```