# how to use ASIHTTPRequest Class for post request to upload a text file to server?

Tags: iphone

I am working on an upload code which will upload the file to the server, which is successfully working

now what I need as fallows:

started with an example-->suppose I have a file named file.txt, whose size is 30MB, when I read the contents of the file it will give me all the 30MB it contains. In the sendSynchronousRequest method I want to give request upto 10mb of data and aging calling the same thing unless it reaches at the last point of file. (in brief I want to use a loop to send the request part by part to the server

to solve the purpose i  read form http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use and Included the ASIHTTPRequest in to my project after inclusion i want to do the same , that will accept a block of data (even via a POST) then append that block of data to a file. It seems to me that you need some kind of client side app that will take a file and break it up into chunks, then send it to your web service one chunk at a time.

My problems:
-how to sent a Post Request from ASIHTTPRequest with a chunk of data?
-do i need to change the PHP  ?

Can any one post a piece of code for both php and ASIHTTPRequest so that i can take a reference from their.

Thank you guys for your continuos support .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a form in the website, it would be easier to use ASIFormDataRequest instead of the standard ASIHTTPRequest. The specific details are here: [Using ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest)

Essentially, you just create the form fields in the website and reference them when you create the request. If you have any text fields in your form you use the

```
[request setPostValue:@"Your value" forKey:@"form key"];
```

The file should be sent through the path using

```
[request setFile:@"filepath to needed file" forKey:@"form key"];
```

If you want you can also send it asynchronously and use the delegate methods for tracking the progress of the upload.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much...                                                    just one help i.e can you post a sample PHP code .for ASIFormDataRequest

Comment: I forgot to mention also check the parameter [request shouldUseRFC2616RedirectBehaviour] because if you set it to NO it would cause your request to be changed to a GET when you get redirected. I had a lot of problems with that.

Comment: I found this code.  http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/1.html  I don't know PHP but it even made sense to me

Answer (score 1):

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

From [ASIHTTPRequest documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following link available on the stack overflow:

[NSURLConnection to upload file asynchonrously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266464/nsurlconnection-to-upload-file-asynchonrously)