# Need assistance regarding NSURLConection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

On my single view I have upload and download option of image and audio file, I successfully implemented the download code with progress bar indicating download progress.

I am having issue in showing uploading progress, currently I am using `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:` but I also want to show upload progress, this method has no callback block or delegate function regarding data progress. So I tried to use `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` but how this method will trigger?

For downloading I am doing this to trigger NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods and getting my job done.

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

If i use `[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:someReq delegate:self]` for uploading, I will be setting delegate twice in one file, first when uploading method is called and second when download method is called, Is this a correct approach?

Finally how `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:` is useful, it has no delegate or callbacks regarding data progress, why to use it?

Comment: Have you tried AFNetworking?

Comment: i dont want to use any library... thanks for reply.

Comment: And why not? =) It's built on top of NSURLConnection!

Comment: I am also trying to learn the basics... after understanding the basics i have no issues.

Comment: I be grateful if you clear my confusion that I asked.

Comment: Have you tried using some other objects as delegates?

Comment: refer the answer by skeo in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266464/nsurlconnection-to-upload-file-asynchonrously

Comment: can any one tell me, is setting delegate twice in single file once for uploading and once for downloading, is correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading and uploading can be two different moments of the application. It does make sense to set `self` twice as delegate, if you create twice the object that is responsible for starting the `NSURLConnection`, otherwise no it doesn't make sense.

The complete method signature is `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` which makes a huge different. In this case you don't need to set a delegate because the response comes in the handler (`NSData` *).

Comment: please one more thing, it not possible to show upload progress through  sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:? am I correct?

Comment: I think you cant with `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`because you only have a `completionHandler` (called when you got what you want). `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`, has been deprecated, so you should not use it.

Comment: then how to upload asynchronously with uploading progress bar?

Comment: You can use this example: http://www.developers-life.com/progress-bar-download-file-on-iphone.html

Comment: connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: is not deprecated, I referred the apple doc.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:

Comment: Its NSURLConnectionDelegate reference, but NSURLConnectionDataDelegate now has this method...  and here is the apple doc ref https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: Use it then... Although I wasn't aware of `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, thanks for the reference.

Comment: you are welcome ... but i am still confused regarding utilising it with both upload and download.. If I am doing this for uploading [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; other delegate methods are also triggering like "didReceiveResponse:", "didReceiveData:", "connectionDidFinishLoading:" I am using these to handle downloading...